# Ignore all letters except for capitals

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have an output like `Johny-Smith`, `Juarez-Hugo`, etc. and I need instead `S`, `H`, etc. Basically, I need the last uppercase letter in a string and that's it. If this is possible in any built in Linux tools (ex awk, sed, grep, etc.) it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need like this ?

```
echo "Johny-Smith" | sed 's/^.*\([A-Z]\)[^A-Z]*$/\1/g'
```

**Test:**

```
$ echo "Johny-Smith-Hello Johny-Smith" | sed 's/.*\([A-Z]\)[^A-Z]*/\1/g'
S
```

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU grep` and if `PCRE` option is available

```
$ echo 'Johny-Smith' | grep -oP '.*\K[A-Z]'
S
$ echo 'Juarez-Hugo' | grep -oP '.*\K[A-Z]'
H
```

- `-o` prints only matched portion
- `-P` Perl regular expression
- `.*\K` positive lookbehind, not part of output
- `[A-Z]` any uppercase character

with `perl`, see [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) for command line options explanation

```
$ # prints the string within captured group
$ echo 'Johny-Smith' | perl -lne 'print /.*([A-Z])/'
S
$ echo 'Juarez-Hugo' | perl -lne 'print /.*([A-Z])/'
H
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of regex. It doesn't work on OS X though.

Comment: change your question to include OSX tag.. many commands behave differently compared to GNU/Linux... if OSX has perl, try `echo "Johny-Smith" | perl -pe 's/.*([A-Z]).*/$1/'`

Answer (score 0):

In Bash:

```
$ var="Johny-Smith-Hello Johny-Smith"; var="${var//[^[:upper:]]/}";echo "${var: -1}"
S
```

- `${var//[^[:upper:]]/}` remove all non-upper case letter chars
- `echo ${var: -1}` output the last one